# randomly showing internal server error 500 what i should do to know exact problem

Tags: php, dynamic-memory-allocation, internal-server-error

My php website is showing randomly internal error 500 and after refreshing many times it works, in errors, memory allocation problem is showing...
but when i am seeing in root directory's error_log  there is no any error. 
Please someone help me to identify the problem.

Thanks for any help!

Here is My php class connection code-

```
class mysql{

public function __construct($db=array()) 
{   
    $default = array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
        'pass' => '*********',
        'db' => 'XXXXXXXXX'
    );



    $db = array_merge($default,$db);
    $this->con=new PDO("mysql:host=".$db['host'].";dbname=".$db['db'].";",$db['user'],$db['pass'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION => true)) or die ('Error connecting to MySQL');
    $this->con->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8
}
}
```

And Here  Is My php file-

```
allow_url_fopen = Off
allow_url_include = On
display_errors = On
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 8M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70"
upload_max_filesize = 2M
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

And This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule php7_module>
  php_flag display_errors On
  php_value max_execution_time 30
  php_value max_input_time 60
  php_value max_input_vars 1000
  php_value memory_limit 256M
  php_value post_max_size 8M
  php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
  php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70"
  php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
  php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
```

In Metrics/Errors It is  Showing

[Thu Aug 30 12:30:17.252514 2018] [:error] [pid 31450:tid 139898017253120] (12)Cannot allocate memory: [client 171.61.187.181:50334] couldn't create child process: /usr/sbin/suphp for /home/abovo/public_html/index.php

Website link is - http://abovo.in/

Comment: Check the error log. It will tell you everything you want to know.

Comment: contact hosting provider

Comment: Use php-fpm with apache's event MPM (or worker MPM). It should allow you to get more child processes while still having the same memory consumption.

Comment: Looks like you runs out of swap memory.Check your free swap availability

Comment: I have seen already in root directory's error_log file but there is nothing i found.

Comment: please tell me sir how to check  free swap memory?

Comment: Are you hosting the site yourself? Or are you using service hosting provider?

Comment: If you're hosting yourself and you have enough memory, simply raising the `memory_limit` could help. But in long run, you need to identify which application is using too much resource. Check your resource usage with `top` command to see what is using the most memory. See if there is any deeper cause to your problem.

Comment: I am using service hosting provider , and as i am seeing in diskUsage  public.html,s  progressbar is full.

Comment: It was a problem of cashe and swap memory , after clearing them my website is ok now  thank you @Nuwan

Comment: @BALAWANTMAURYA since slack comments may get deleted once expired i have added an answer section for others who will search for the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You should check your server resources.Specially the `swap` area and `disk` storage.Allocating more resources will let PHP to execute your application without memory issues.

If you are using linux then you could check them with following commands

Check swap

```
swapon --summary
```

Check free RAM with

```
free -h
```

Check disk storage with

```
df -h
```

Comment: Sir please check my pdo connection , If  there is a problem please provide me a correct solution, i am asking this just for my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

One More Thing I want To Mention Here, I was using "!" in my password, this is a exception, server shows a problem if you are using this, so simply do not use ! in your password.